# advanced css: target last adjacent sibling

Tags: css, angularjs

I am trying to target the last adjacent sibling in a situation where I don't know how many siblings there will be (1 to 6).  See this plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/JBsMUg2yl1JkbK6j8Bfj?p=preview

```
   <section>
    <div class="c">Category 1</div>
    <div class="c">Category 2</div>
    <div class="p">product</div>
    <div class="p">product</div>
    <div class="p">product</div>
    <div class="c">Category 3</div>
    <div class="p">product</div>
    <div class="p">product</div>
    <div class="c">Category 4</div>
    <div class="c">Category 5</div>
    <div class="p">product</div>
    <div class="p">product</div>
    <div class="p">product</div>
    <div class="c">Category 6</div>
    <div class="c">Category 7</div>
    <div class="c">Category 8</div>
    <div class="p">product</div>
    <div class="c">Category 9</div>
  </section>
```

My best efforts still left me with this missing: Category 3 SHOULD be selected; Category 7 should NOT be selected.

```
div {
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.c {
    color: yellow;
    background: blue;
    opacity:.1;
}
.c+.c {
    opacity:1;
}
.p+.c { 
    color: yellow;
    background: blue;
}

.c:last-child { /* orphan cat on end of list */
     opacity:.1;
}
```

I cannot easily change my html, nor put a class on the last adjacent sibling.

The background: this is a catalog rendered by angular ng-repeat on a flat array that contains category headings followed by products.  The ng-repeat uses a text filter (from a search box) which ignores the category headings (otherwise they would likely all be hidden) and applies only to the products. I therefore end up with a situation where I have empty category heading which I want to remove via css (but other suggestions are welcome)

Comment: You'll need JS for this. CSS can't use pseudo-classes to select by **class** only elements.

Comment: I didn't understand the selection pattern...

Comment: I think you should be using nested ordered lists (`<ul><li><ul><li></li>...</ul></li>...</ul>`) for this.

Comment: What do you mean by “last adjacent sibling”? Sibling of what? Last in which set? Adjacent to what?

Comment: Adjacent sibling: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors so if I've got several consecutive elements of same type/ class and I only want to select the last one (or anything but the last one) AND I don't know the number of elements I'm going to have...

Answer (score 0):

I changed the HTML code and used the title-Attribute as well as the CSS visibility property. Thats the only solution I can imagine right now.

```css
.c {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.c ul {
  visibility: visible;
}
.c ul:before {
  content: attr(title);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="c">
    Category 1
  </li>
  <li class="c">
    Category 2
    <ul title="Category 2">
      <li class="p">product</li>
      <li class="p">product</li>
      <li class="p">product</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="c">
    Category 3
    <ul title="Category 3">
      <li class="p">product</li>
      <li class="p">product</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="c">
    Category 4
  </li>
  <li class="c">
    Category 5
    <ul title="Category 5">
      <li class="p">product</li>
      <li class="p">product</li>
      <li class="p">product</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="c">
    Category 6
  </li>
  <li class="c">
    Category 7
  </li>
  <li class="c">
    Category 8
    <ul title="Category 8">
      <li class="p">product</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="c">
    Category 9
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How does that solve the problem?  How would you hide Category 4 for instance, whose only uniquness is that it's empty?  There are no parent selectors available in today's css...

Comment: BTW: my html is perfectly valid.  You may mean it is not semantic but that is ok for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

The solution shown here: http://plnkr.co/edit/6DUHUEHC9j5mONGG1z0N?p=preview will work as far as creating the visual effect I need.

It uses separate `<ul>` for each category and `:only-child` pseudo selector.

However, it is actually not an acceptable answer to the question because it required changing the html which was undesirable.  I think there should still be a solution for a flat list of elements using some combination of nth child / last child / not(), etc. but haven't found it yet.